# How to add icons with dropdown with actions to Ubuntu Panel

Tags: scripts, indicator, shortcuts, panel

I have some scripts/programs which I run often. How can I add an icon to Panel for e.g. like Dropbox which when on clicked provides a dropdown menu with several options, each option on clicking runs a shell script or a program with some arguments (nice to have - report success or failure) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom launcher icon to execute your scripts. Open your favourite text editor and copy the snippet below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=My Scripts
Name[de]=Meine Skripte
Exec=myscript_0.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=terminal
StartupNotify=true
Actions=ContextMenu1;ContextMenu2

[Desktop Action ContextMenu1]
Name=Run script 1
Name[de]=Skript 1 starten
Exec=myscript_1.sh

[Desktop Action ContextMenu2]
Name=Run script 2
Name[de]=Skript 2 starten
Exec=myscript_2.sh
```

Now it's time to modify this stub above, as it will not be useful as it is for you!

#### `[Desktop Entry]` section:

- `Encoding=UTF-8` Better **not modify** this line, because otherwise you will get problems if you use any non-ASCII characters in this file.
- `Name=...` Enter any string here, it will be the default English name of the launcher item.
- `Name[de]=...` Same as `Name=`, but for the German (de) translation.
  *It's just an example, you may remove all these lines with `[de]` or replace them with another locale code.*
- `Exec=...` Enter the command you want to execute if the launcher icon is clicked here.
   If the script is located in a folder listed in the `$PATH` environment variable, the executable's name only is enough, otherwise you have to specify the full path.
   Make sure that there's no typo and that the script is executable (`chmod +x` and it starts with a valid "shebang" line)!

  - `Terminal=true` If you set it to `false` instead, no terminal window will be opened and the script will run in background.
  - `Type=Application` Do **not change** this line.
  - `Icon=terminal` Specifies the icon of the launcher item. You may use generic names like `terminal` or enter the full path to an image file.
  - `StartupNotify=true` Causes the mouse pointer to perform the "waiting" animation (spinning circle/hourglass) in the time between clicking the icon and when the window opens. You may set it to `false` if you want.
  - `Actions=...` Lists the internal identifier names for the context menu entries. They have to match those used in the context menu section headlines (`[Desktop Action ...]`) and need to be a semicolon-separated list without spaces.

#### `[Desktop Action ...]` sections:

You only need the keys `Name` (and translations like `Name[de]`, if you want) and `Exec` here. The same criteria as above apply here as well.

Also make sure again that the identifier (here `ContextMenu1` and `ContextMenu2`) in the section headline appear in the `Actions=` list above!

The number of such context menu blocks is unlimited.

---

After you modified the example stub above, save it in the directory `~/.local/share/applications/` with a custom file name, but the extension `.desktop`.

Then it should appear in your Unity Dash's Application Lens (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). If it does not, log out and back in to update it. Then drag it from the Dash onto the launcher bar with your mouse. A right-click on it will open the context menu where all "Desktop Action" items are listed, like in the example screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer doesn't provide a way to create an indicator, however it does provide an alternative. The core idea is to use graphical list of script to launch them.

**Script**

The script bellow uses array of full paths to favorite scripts , which user may want to launch. The following script is suggested to be saved in personal `$HOME/bin` folder and made executable with `chmod +x`. It can further be linked to a keyboard shortcut to easily call the launcher, or alternatively - placed into a `.desktop` shortcut as shown in ByteCommander's answer.

Follow the suggestion in the comments of the script for modifying it to suit your needs

```
#!/bin/bash
# -------------------------------
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: Nov 10th, 2015
# Description: A launcher for favorite scripts
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/693413/295286
#---------------------------------

# ARRAY holds full paths to scripts that you want to launch
# Always enclose paths in double quotes, separate by spaces

ARRAY=("/home/xieerqi/bin/sh/resizer.sh" "/home/xieerqi/bin/sh/verticalSplit.sh" "/home/xieerqi/bin/sh/vol-down.sh"  )

# This launches zenity dialog with the list from ARRAY
# Stores into SCRIPT variable
SCRIPT="$( zenity --list --title "Select script to run" --column "Script files" "${ARRAY[@]}" | cut -d '|' -f1)"

# If SCRIPT variable is empty, do nothing, fail silently
# If exists, check if user has executable permissions
# Implies script existence
if  [ -n "$SCRIPT" ];then
  if  [ -x "$SCRIPT" ] ; then
    # if you want to see script running in terminal
    # replace the line bellow with  xterm -hold -e "$SCRIPT" 
    "$SCRIPT" &
   else
    zenity --error --text "File doesn't exist or wrong permission "
  fi
fi
```

**Screenshot**

[image]